# Route Post não está a ser reconhecida (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, post

Boas, ainda sou novo a utilizar o Laravel 5, mas estou com um problema de Routes que não encontro solução em lado nenhum (apenas o mesmo problema [Aqui](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-routing-issue-for-post-methods) e sem nenhuma solução viável)

Passo a explicar, no ficheiro routes.php quando eu tento definir uma rota usando **POST** ela não é reconhecida!

Entre outras rotas tenho esta:

```
Route::post('guarda-terreno',[
'as'=>'guardaTerrenoPost',
'uses'=>'TerrenoController@store',]);
```

Esta rota deve receber os dados de um formulário.
Quando tento ver as rotas definidas: `php artisan route:list` essa rota não aparece na listagem. Mais esquisito, é que se eu mudar para

```
Route::get('guarda-terreno',[
'as'=>'guardaTerrenoPost',
'uses'=>'TerrenoController@store',]);
```

ela já aparece na lista!

Já tentei assim:

```
Route::post('guarda-terreno', 'TerrenoController@store');
```

E não dá!

Se usar`Route::any('guarda-terreno', 'TerrenoController@store');` ele já me regista todos os métodos `| GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE |`quando eu queria só o POST!

O que é que não estou a ver aqui?!

Comment: já tentou `Route::match(['post'],'guarda-terreno',[
'as'=>'guardaTerrenoPost',
'uses'=>'TerrenoController@store',]);` ??

Comment: Ainda não tinha experimentado assim... Assim já funcionou, já só tenho uma rota POST para o método "store" em vez de 6! Existe alguma razão em especial para que Route::post('guarda-terreno', 'TerrenoController@store'); não dar e a sua solução funcione?
Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: é penas com essa rota que está dando esse problema ?

Comment: dá-me o mesmo problema com todas as rotas Post... independentemente do modelo e do método! Como é um problema "raro" (pois não encontrei nenhuma solução facilmente) vou supor que é problema meu e mudei alguma configuração onde não devia! A sua solução funciona, por isso vou adoptá-la, num novo protejo "limpo" lá verifico se funciona o POST novamente! Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei por que assim não está funcionando, aconselho a você a abrir um issue [aqui](https://github.com/laravel/framework) reportando o erro.

Uma outra maneira de se utilizar o route post é pela function match, passando 'post' dentro de um array no primeiro parâmetro

```
Route::match(['post'],'guarda-terreno',[ 
'as'=>'guardaTerrenoPost', 
'uses'=>'TerrenoController@store',]
);
```

Não ha diferença entre uma função ou outra, em relação a desempenho, então aconselho usar essa em seu projeto

Answer (score 0):

Por que precisa dessa `,]` no final? O problema talvez seja por que já existe uma outra rota pra essa action, TerrenoController@store que também é post, talvez você tenha configurado um Route::resource e está tentando criar um Route::post, aí deve ta gerando conflito. Mas se não for nada disso, tenta remover essa `,]`. O correto seria:

```
Route::post('guarda-terreno',[
      'as'=>'guardaTerrenoPost',
      'uses'=>'TerrenoController@store'
   ]
);
```